# Group and Trigger multiple Azure Pipelines at once

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have more than 30 pipelines configured in our Azure DevOps for each environment based on the Microservices.

We are looking for an option to group all 30 pipelines and trigger at once, instead of triggering each pipeline subsequently.

If there is a possibility to group 5 to 6 pipelines and trigger the build at one shot and do the same for rest. The concept of bundling the pipelines.

We are unable to get the solution for the same.Request you to help in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a build that trigger the other builds, in this build add the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) as many time is necessery.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll try your option and let you know the outcome.

I have one more query. What should be the source for this pipeline. I can't choose a service repository. Do I need to create a dummy/test repository for this or should I just select any repo from git.


Thanks,
Usha

Comment: You can choose any git repo and in the options mark the checkbox "Don't sync sources", then the repo will not be downloaded at all.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to execute the same but its failing with the error " The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.". I have provided the same token using which I cant run the builds individually.

Comment: In the "Authentication Configuration" choose "OAuth", and in the "Agent Job" settings mark the checkbox "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token".

Comment: I have tried all the possible options but still no go. Getting the same error The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.

Comment: I'm selecting the Agent job/pool as Hosted Ubuntu 1604

Comment: I don't know :/ it should works (if you have permissions).

Comment: Okay. Just to make sure I'm providing the correct credentials. Please confirm is it looking for git credentials or the access to pipeline, because i'm just a contributor to the project and creating the pipelines. If individual pipelines are working with the same credentials then Build task should work. Hope i'm not missing anything here

Comment: Thanks @ Shayki Abramczyk .. Its working now. I didn't add the same token in Azure devops with relevant access. After adding it in security, it worked fine.

Comment: @ushachokka If this was the solution for you, could you mark it as the answer? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with this, and I have this so far

```
parameters:
- name: pipelines
  type: object
  default:
    - sampleA
    - sampleB

variables:
  - group: pipeline # contains PAT as a secret

steps:
  - ${{ each pipeline in parameters.pipelines }}:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      env:
        AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(pat)
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: azure # not really used, but required
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az pipelines build queue --definition-name ${{ pipeline }} --org https://dev.azure.com/yourorg --project yourproject
```

it works, but needs a collection and reporting task as well, may oist something when I get those working too

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Leif's example. I had to do the following to make his example work in our devops instance.

1. Edit pipeline after creation and click the 'ellipsis menu>Triggers' then select the 'Variables' tab and map the variables group you saved your PAT secret in.
2. The azureSubscription definitely needs to be connected to a service connection with a service principle that has the required permissions to run the az cli command to queue the build. (So is very much used and important)

Hope this helps someone out there.

@Leif Apologies for posting as answer and not commenting on yours but, apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment on posts. :(